# How to use byte like the following example

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell my how this guy, who gives the code example, is able to use `byte`?

[Example of AES using Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306956/example-of-aes-using-crypto)

Like this line:

```
byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
```

and

```
std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i])) << " ";
```

I tried copy-paste, but I can't create `byte` variables.

Comment: Did you include the same headers?

Comment: He knew that `std::byte` would get added to the standard before anyone else.

Comment: simple the type byte is defined by crypto++ config.h file

Comment: https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/config_8h_source.html line 228

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have do define that like this

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

because the char type doesen't reach decimal value 255 so you have to define an unsigned char type.
Anyway it works

Answer (score 0):

The type "byte" is defined in some of the header files that is included in the example. To use exactly the same type, you have to include the same header files.

Comment: It's not, look at the date of the answer.

Comment: @SombreroChicken you are correct - editing my answer accordingly.