# Cryptopp and Mingw-w64 Crash on Win 7

Tags: c++, windows, mingw-w64, crypto++

Good day,

I'm compiling some C++ examples using "Cryptopp 8.2.0" and "Mingw-w64" on Windows 7 (x64) and all crash when executing.
The examples are "Crypto++ GCM Test" (from Cryptopp site) and others that I have found here on Stack. All compile OK.
The strange thing is that I tested this same setup 2 weeks ago (before a full OS reinstall) and I didn't experience crashes.

Cryptopp 8.2.0
Downloaded this build and used "libcryptopp.a"
https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-crypto++

Mingw-w64
gcc-10.2.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1

Windows 7 Crash Log
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   a.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  5f77518e
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_dbce
Fault Module Version:   6.1.7601.24384
Fault Module Timestamp: 5c6e245d
Exception Code: c0000374
Exception Offset:   00000000000bf302
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   dbce
Additional Information 2:   dbce16d62f50f2b2931f8e5692998f10
Additional Information 3:   8f4d
Additional Information 4:   8f4dc2cb1c713a0218de25ff7b749f7d

Also tested with gcc-10.1 (previous version but same crashes).
I appreciate the help.
Thanks

Edit

- This example cryptopp.com/wiki/GCM_Mode#AEAD (Only crashes no output)
- This example [Example of AES using Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306956/example-of-aes-using-crypto) (Shows output but then crashes)
- Compiling OK like this: g++ Driver.cpp -lcryptopp
- Tested the same setup Mingw64+Cryptopp on Win 8 and had the same crash.

Comment: Which example are you exactly trying to compile/execute? How are you compiling it? Please add all necessary information in your question. "code found here on stack overflow" is a totally vague term. Edit : The c0000374 error code indicates memory corruption -- the application is trying to use or access memory it doesn't have access to.

Comment: Post relevant code here.

Comment: @brc-dd One of the examples is https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GCM_Mode#AEAD Downloaded the ZIP and just compiled.
I researched and tested several things but nothing works.
Compiling OK like this: 
g++ Driver.cpp -lcryptopp
Thanks

Comment: @brc-dd Forgot to add that I also tested the same setup (Mingw64+Cryptopp) on Win 8 and had same crash. Thanks

Comment: @Mike Are you getting anything as output? In my case I am getting this as output : `Decrypted and Verified data. Ready for use.

adata length: 16
pdata length: 16

cipher text:
 CEA7403D4D606B6E 074EC5D3BAF39D18 AE9B1771DBA9CF62 B39BE017940330B4

recovered adata length: 16
recovered pdata length: 16` I believe this is the expected output. Although: I am on windows 10, but I don't think that should matter as version of `g++` and `crypto++` are same. I am getting core dump and an exit code of `127`, but that is not affecting program output nor printing anything on `stderr`.

Comment: @brc-dd On cryptopp.com/wiki/GCM_Mode#AEAD I dont get ouput, just crash. But testing an example found here for AES-CBS I get output and then crashes.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, same is happening with me. It prints output then crashes. Sometimes crashes even without printing any output. It appears to me more or less a msys bug. Have you tried manually installing cryptopp (without using msys package)? As far as I remember, when one manually builds it then after running `make`, there a script is run which tests code for all possible encryption methods. I think you should try doing that. If any error is pointed during that test script then the bug is with cryptopp library itself (I hardly doubt that).

Comment: @brc-dd I did not build manually because I was having difficulties and lack  experience with make. I will re-try and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @brc-dd I successfully built the library using MSYS+MINGW64+MAKE. Its not crashing anymore. Thanks for the input.