# How to implement AES in crypto++ which is applied multiple times to an input? which AES mode?

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

For my target application I want to use AES multiple times in a row for a given input.
After encrypting it $i$ times in a row it should result in same starting input if decrypting it $i$ times backwards.

Given some example [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306956/example-of-aes-using-crypto) I already implemented some working solution:

```
//g++ -o aestest aestest.cpp -lcryptopp    
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"
#include <cassert>

void dispBA(std::vector<byte> &bav, std::string text =""){
    std::cout << text << " : size "<< bav.size() <<" byte"<< std::endl;
    for( long unsigned int i = 0; i < bav.size(); i++ ) {
         std::cout << std::dec<< (int)((static_cast<byte>(bav[i]))) << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}

void encryptBV(CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption &cbcEncryption, std::vector<byte> &bytesIn, std::vector<byte> &bytesCrypOut, bool disp=false){
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::ArraySink( &bytesCrypOut[0],bytesCrypOut.size()  ), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING );
    stfEncryptor.Put(  &bytesIn[0], bytesIn.size() );
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
    if(disp)dispBA(bytesCrypOut, "Cipher numbers");
}

void decryptBV(CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption &cbcDecryption, std::vector<byte> &bytesCrypIn, std::vector<byte> &bytesDecrOut, bool disp=false){
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::ArraySink( &bytesDecrOut[0], bytesDecrOut.size()  ), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING  );
    stfDecryptor.Put( &bytesCrypIn[0], bytesCrypIn.size() );
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
    if(disp)dispBA(bytesDecrOut, "Decrypted numbers");
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //Key 32 bytes -> aes256
    //block size always 16
    const int myKeysize = 32;
    byte key[ myKeysize ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    memset( key, 0x00, myKeysize ); // no key set yet
    memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );
    
    //encryption
    std::vector<byte> bytesCryp(myKeysize);
    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, myKeysize);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );
    
    //decryption
    std::vector<byte> bytesDecr(myKeysize);   
    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, myKeysize);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );
        
    std::vector<byte> bytesIn = {0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11, 12, 13 ,14 ,15 ,16, 17, 18 ,19 ,20 ,21 ,22 ,23 ,24 ,25 ,26 ,27 ,28 ,29 ,30,31};
    assert(bytesIn.size()== myKeysize); 
    dispBA(bytesIn, "Starting number");
    
    //-----does work for single en/decryption
    // Create Cipher numbers    
    //encryptBV(cbcEncryption, bytesIn, bytesCryp, true);    
    // Decrypt
    //decryptBV(cbcDecryption, bytesCryp, bytesDecr, true);
    
    int count = 42;
    for(int i=0; i < count; i++){       
        cbcEncryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, myKeysize, iv ); // ++
        encryptBV(cbcEncryption, bytesIn, bytesCryp); 
        cbcEncryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, myKeysize, iv ); // ++
        encryptBV(cbcEncryption, bytesCryp, bytesIn);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){ 
        cbcDecryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, myKeysize, iv ); // ++
        decryptBV(cbcDecryption, bytesIn, bytesCryp);   
        cbcDecryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, myKeysize, iv ); // ++
        decryptBV(cbcDecryption, bytesCryp, bytesIn);
    }
    dispBA(bytesIn, "end"); // this does only return the correct value if lines marked with ++ are added
    
    //-----but it does also work if I repeat them without changing the inputs--- ["W2"]
    // Create Cipher numbers    
    //encryptBV(cbcEncryption, bytesIn, bytesCryp, true);    
    //encryptBV(cbcEncryption, bytesIn, bytesCryp, true);   
    // Decrypt
    //decryptBV(cbcDecryption, bytesCryp, bytesDecr, true);
    //decryptBV(cbcDecryption, bytesCryp, bytesDecr, true);


    return 0;
}
```

However currently this only works if I reset the key after every message (or generate new ExternalCipher). I though the key is only changed during the rounds at a single (128,196,256-bit) message (or inside a long) and not continue through messages.

Is there a better way to do this? Or why this happen and does not happen if I don't change the input (see ["W2"])?

[Here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Modes_of_Operation) I found different mode of operation. I guess those are different implementation of AES. Should I use a certain? (edit: ECB? its not supported afaik)

Comment: What does "modi" mean in this context?

Comment: @bmm6o did some edit is reference to https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Modes_of_Operation there are different types how AES opperates with the key

Comment: I've migrated this question from [cryptography.se] because it depends on reading through the code. If the key is changed during the execution then this is code / library specific, and not a detail of the AES algorithm definition. Crypto++ is one of the most used libraries and seems well maintained. I'll remove the question if it is a good choice because that's opinionated (Crypto++ does have a very specific way of working).

Comment: By the way, it is probably that you need to reset the IV rather than CBC. In some protocols the IV is taken from the last ciphertextblock of the message, so it makes sense to keep the "vector" to the last setting. I would not recommend stacking CBC encryption. If you just want to encrypt another AES key of 128 or 256 bits then ECB would suffice. In that case you don't need an IV. There is generally no need to encrypt a key multiple times if you use AES, you could however use AES in SIV mode or use a specific AES key wrap mechanism.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes SIV mode? I think crypto++ does not support this. I dont want to use it the classical way. It should serve as symmetric pseudo random number generator were each element can serve as initial element. Given two numbers it should be hard to determine if there are in the same cycle. Given two random elements of a cycle it should be hard to determine the number of steps in between them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ECB mode listed at [crypto++ Modes of Operation](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Modes_of_Operation) but! crypto++ has some shown [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ECB_Mode) with this I can do some small rewrite:

```
//ecb
void encryptBV(CryptoPP::ECB_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Encryption &ecbEncryption, std::vector<byte> &bytesIn, std::vector<byte> &bytesCrypOut, bool disp=false){
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(ecbEncryption, new CryptoPP::ArraySink( &bytesCrypOut[0],bytesCrypOut.size()  ), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING );
    stfEncryptor.Put(  &bytesIn[0], bytesIn.size() );
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
    if(disp)dispBA(bytesCrypOut, "Cipher number");
}

void decryptBV(CryptoPP::ECB_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Decryption &ecbDecryption, std::vector<byte> &bytesCrypIn, std::vector<byte> &bytesDecrOut, bool disp=false){
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(ecbDecryption, new CryptoPP::ArraySink( &bytesDecrOut[0], bytesDecrOut.size()  ), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING  );
    stfDecryptor.Put( &bytesCrypIn[0], bytesCrypIn.size() );
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
    if(disp)dispBA(bytesDecrOut, "Decrypted number");
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //Key 32 bytes -> aes256
    //block size always 16
    const int myKeysize = 32;
    byte key[ myKeysize ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    memset( key, 0x00, myKeysize ); // no key set yet
    memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );
    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Encryption ecbEncryption;
    ecbEncryption.SetKey( key, myKeysize);
    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Decryption ecbDecryption;
    ecbDecryption.SetKey( key, myKeysize);
    std::vector<byte> bytesCryp(myKeysize);
    std::vector<byte> bytesDecr(myKeysize);

    std::vector<byte> bytesIn = {0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11, 12, 13 ,14 ,15 ,16, 17, 18 ,19 ,20 ,21 ,22 ,23 ,24 ,25 ,26 ,27 ,28 ,29 ,30,31};
    dispBA(bytesIn, "Starting number");

    //test single encrypt, decrypt
    encryptBV(ecbEncryption, bytesIn, bytesCryp, true);
    decryptBV(ecbDecryption, bytesCryp, bytesDecr, true);

    int count = 42;
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        encryptBV(ecbEncryption, bytesIn, bytesCryp);
        encryptBV(ecbEncryption, bytesCryp, bytesIn);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        decryptBV(ecbDecryption, bytesIn, bytesCryp);
        decryptBV(ecbDecryption, bytesCryp, bytesIn);
    }
    dispBA(bytesIn, "end");
}
```

It also runs faster (about 60%).

**Warning:** this is not secure for normal AES usage.

(if someone else found some better way I can change the correct answer)

Comment: I followed the link and found ECB as the very first method: " Crypto++ offers several modes of operation, including ECB ...", which points to the URL you posted https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ECB_Mode

Comment: @MaartenBodewes whoops, I only checked the list in section Wide Block Ciphers