# Selection of cryptlib or cryptopp?

Tags: visual-studio, crypto++

I was compiling the Crypto++ library and there are 4 projects in the Visual Studio solution:

- cryptest
- cryptlib
- cryptopp
- dlltest

What is the meaning of cryptlib and cryptopp? In a project that use Crypto++, which of these I should be use?

Comment: See the ReadME: http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/c5/ - duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619042/how-do-i-install-crypto-in-visual-studio-2010-windows-7

Comment: `cryptlib` is the static LIB, while `cryptopp` is a dynamic DLL. Its probably easiest to use the static version `cryptlib`. But you might need to change a setting to use `cryptlib` in your projects. To change the setting, see the discussion of "Static Versus Dynamic Linking" at [Compiling and Integrating Crypto++ into the Microsoft Visual C++ Environment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16388/Compiling-and-Integrating-Crypto-into-the-Microsof).