# Link errors using cryptopp on VS2012 static library, console application and clr program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, static-libraries, crypto++

I have the following project structure on VS2012 C++:

`cryptopp`: As downloaded and build from cryptopp project.

`AccessLib`: A static library build using cryptopp functions.

`TestApp`: A Win32 console application that uses AccessLib (and cryptolib indirectly)

`UserApp`: A Windows interactive application with CLR support (`/clr`) that uses AccessLib (and cryptolib indirectly)

Well, my first try was to make this solution work to build my console application and my windows application. BTW, `cryptopp` was build in a way described in manuals and  [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619042/how-do-i-install-crypto-in-visual-studio-2010). All tests from cryptopp project are running fine in the build environment.

Here is how I´ve build my project:

- Set `AccessLib` as being `/Mtd` or `/MT` for Debug or Release respectively, linking with `cryptolib.lib` from `cryptodir\Win32\Output\Debug` and `cryptodir\Win32\Output\Release`respectively.
- Set `TestApp` as being also `/MTd` or `/MT` for Debug or Release respectively, linking to `AccessLib.lib` generated from step above.

Fine till now, but when building `UserApp`it does not work as `TestApp` needs `/clr` and that´s incompatible with `MTd`or `/MT`.

So, here goes my first question: I can´t have a CLR program that links to a static library that has `/MTd`or `/MT`.... What should I do to build my `/clr` program to my static library `AccessLib.lib` that access `cryptopp` as a static library also ? Should I need to convert everything to DLL project ?

Well, I even tried to convert to use cryptopp as a DLL, that way:

- Set `AccessLib` as being `/MDd` or `/MD` for Debug or Release respectively, linking with `cryptolib.lib` from `cryptodir\Win32\DLL_Output\Debug` and `cryptodir\Win32\DLL_Output\Release`respectively.

That step went fine, but when trying to build `TestApp` as being also `/MDd` or `/MD` for Debug or Release respectively, linking to `AccessLib.lib` generated from step above, I got several errors like:

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: TestApp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>cryptlib.lib(hrtimer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in TestApp.obj
1>cryptlib.lib(pch.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in TestApp.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in cryptlib.lib(hrtimer.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in cryptlib.lib(hrtimer.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in cryptlib.lib(hrtimer.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::locale::id::id(unsigned int)" (??0id@locale@std@@QAE@I@Z) already defined in cryptlib.lib(pch.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned char * __thiscall CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,0>::allocate(unsigned int,void const *)" (?allocate@?$AllocatorWithCleanup@E$0A@@CryptoPP@@QAEPAEIPBX@Z) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,0>::deallocate(void *,unsigned int)" (?deallocate@?$AllocatorWithCleanup@E$0A@@CryptoPP@@QAEXPAXI@Z) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned char * __thiscall CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,0>::reallocate(unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int,bool)" (?reallocate@?$AllocatorWithCleanup@E$0A@@CryptoPP@@QAEPAEPAEII_N@Z) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,0>::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,0>(void)" (??0?$AllocatorWithCleanup@E$0A@@CryptoPP@@QAE@XZ) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::Enc(void)" (??0Enc@Rijndael@CryptoPP@@QAE@XZ) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::~Enc(void)" (??1Enc@Rijndael@CryptoPP@@UAE@XZ) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::Enc(class CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc const &)" (??0Enc@Rijndael@CryptoPP@@QAE@ABV012@@Z) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static char const * __cdecl CryptoPP::CBC_ModeBase::StaticAlgorithmName(void)" (?StaticAlgorithmName@CBC_ModeBase@CryptoPP@@SAPBDXZ) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::CBC_Encryption::CBC_Encryption(void)" (??0CBC_Encryption@CryptoPP@@QAE@XZ) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall CryptoPP::CBC_Encryption::~CBC_Encryption(void)" (??1CBC_Encryption@CryptoPP@@UAE@XZ) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::~StreamTransformationFilter(void)" (??1StreamTransformationFilter@CryptoPP@@UAE@XZ) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::StringSinkTemplate<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &)" (??0?$StringSinkTemplate@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@CryptoPP@@QAE@AAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::~StringSinkTemplate<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(void)" (??1?$StringSinkTemplate@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@CryptoPP@@UAE@XZ) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>cryptopp.lib(cryptopp.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::Exception::Exception(enum CryptoPP::Exception::ErrorType,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Exception@CryptoPP@@QAE@W4ErrorType@01@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>accesslib.lib(Encryptor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const & const CryptoPP::g_nullNameValuePairs" (?g_nullNameValuePairs@CryptoPP@@3ABVNameValuePairs@1@B)
1>c:\project\dev\accesslib\Debug\TestApp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I did not move to build `UserApp` with that configuration.

Help is appreciated to make this whole thing work together. I want to avoid usage of DLL´s at all. My original idea is to have everything as static libraries, but I don´t know if I can achieve that on that solution configuration.

Help appreciated.

Comment: You must rebuild cryptlib with /MDd as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not link a library compiled with MT or MTd to a  program complied with MD or MDd. They have different CRT library.

You can rebuild cryptopp with MD or MDd

Comment: I don't believe there's an ABI difference. The runtime function names, arguments and return values are the same regardless of static runtime linking vs dynamic runtime linking.

Answer (score 1):

> That step went fine, but when trying to build TestApp as being also /MDd or /MD for Debug or Release respectively, linking to AccessLib.lib generated from step above, I got several errors like...

You are mixing and matching runtimes. You should probably change Crypto++ and make it use dynamic runtime linking the the C/C++ runtime library. See [Visual Studio | Dynamic Runtime Linking](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio#Dynamic_Runtime_Linking) on the Crypto++ wiki.

---

> I want to avoid usage of DLL´s at all. My original idea is to have everything as static libraries, but I don´t know if I can achieve that on that solution configuration.

Yes, this is preferred. It will work, but you need to build the Crypto++ static library using dynamic runtime linking. The project you want is ***`cryptlib`***, and its output is found in *`<crypto++ dir>/Output/{Debug|Release}/{Win32|x64}`*. See the previous links.

You should also avoid the FIPS DLL. The DLL project is ***`cryptdll`***, and its output is found in *`<crypto++ dir>/DLL_Output/...`*. The DLL is special purpose, and it only provides FIPS algorithms. Its not a general purpose DLL, it lacks most stuff you need, and it causes a lot of pain and misery.

I even go so far as to tell people to completely delete the ***`cryptdll`*** and ***`dlltest`*** projects because they cause so much trouble. Also see [FIPS DLL](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FIPS_DLL) on the Crypto++ wiki.

---

> Link errors using cryptopp on VS2012 static library, console application and clr program

This is noteworthy... Crypto++ does not use the ***[`/clr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)*** option. You will need to modify the static library project settings and add it.

The static library's project is called ***`cryptlib`***. You will need to do it for *Win32 Debug*, *Win32 Release*, *x64 Debug* and *x64 Release*.